# Update Table, keep only first 2 charcacters

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update my table Column. The updated column should have only the first 2 characters of the string the cell contains.
For example:

Column Name of table Users has the balue THOMAS, and i want to update so the updated column Name will be just TH.

i have tried

```
UPDATE users SET Initial = LEFT(LTRIM(Name), 2)
```

but returns:

> SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
> 01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: It seems you don't have the `Initial` column that you try to set to. From your description I think you need to set to `Name`, i.e. `UPDATE users SET Name = LEFT(LTRIM(Name), 2) `

Comment: "Name" is the column you want to read and which column you want to update?

Comment: @AlexLarionov yes you were right, but still returning ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier

Comment: @CleanBold i want to read and update Name Columns

Comment: Consider using a virtual column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR` in oracle as follows:

```
UPDATE USERS
   SET INITIAL = SUBSTR( NAME, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Any way i can implement this in an insert query from one DB table to another?

Comment: @Art `INSERT INTO tab_a (SELECT SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 2) FROM tab_b)`